# Remove the selected options from next part when one of the part have selected the option

Tags: javascript

I make a box for user input to the number of part they want using loop. I implement the multiSelect plugin from [this website](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/multi-select-filter-checkbox.html) into the category section. How can I make the category option disabled or remove it when one of the part's category selections has been selected. Below is my code and javascript:

```
<body>
<div class="modal-body flex flex-col">
   <div>
      <label for="part_input">How many part do you want?</label>
      <input class="rounded-md mx-3" type="number" name="input" id="input" min="1"
                        max="10" style="height: 30px;width: 100px" placeholder="e.g. 1" required>
      <button type="submit" id="generateFields" class="bg-blue-500 rounded"
                        style="width: 80px; height: 30px;">Enter</button>
   </div>
   <form method="POST" action="">
      <div id="partContainer"></div>
         <div class="float-right mt-4" id="buttons" style="display: none">
            <button type="button" class="bg-blue-400 rounded hover:bg-blue-300"
                            style="width: 100px">Create</button>
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="border bg-white rounded hover:bg-gray-100"
                            style="width: 100px; margin-left:10px">Cancel</button>
         </div>
   </form>
</div>
</body>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const generateButton = document.getElementById("generateFields");
        const partContainer = document.getElementById("partContainer");
        const buttonsDiv = document.getElementById('buttons');


        generateButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const numberOfParts = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);

            if (numberOfParts >= 1 && numberOfParts <= 10) {
                partContainer.innerHTML = "";
 
                for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfParts; i++) {
                    const partDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    partDiv.innerHTML = `
                        <h4 style="font-size:20px; margin-top:25px"><b>Part ${i}</b></h4>
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <label for="partName${i}" class="w-32 pr-2 mt-4">Name</label>
                            <input class="rounded-md" type="text" name="part_name${i}" id="part_name${i}" placeholder="Name"
                                style="height: 30px; margin:15px 0px 0px 20px;width:175px;" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <label for="partAmount${i}" class="w-32 pr-2 mt-4">Amount</label>
                            <input class="rounded-md" type="number" step="0.01" name="allocation_amount${i}" id="allocation_amount${i}" placeholder="0.00"
                                style="height: 30px; margin:15px 0px 0px 20px;text-align:right;width:175px;" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex">
                            <label for="partCategory${i}" class="w-32 pr-2 mt-4">Category</label>
                            <select class="rounded-md categorySelect"  name="category_id${i}" id="category_id${i}" multiple
                                required>
                                <option name="category_id${i}[]" value="{{ $category->category_id }}" data-part="${i}">
                                        Food & drink
                                    </option>
                                    <option name="category_id${i}[]" value="{{ $category->category_id }}" data-part="${i}">
                                        Shopping
                                    </option>
                                    <option name="category_id${i}[]" value="{{ $category->category_id }}" data-part="${i}">
                                        Income
                                    </option>
                                    <option name="category_id${i}[]" value="{{ $category->category_id }}" data-part="${i}">
                                        Travel
                                    </option>
                                    <option name="category_id${i}[]" value="{{ $category->category_id }}" data-part="${i}">
                                        Housing
                                    </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    `;

                    partContainer.appendChild(partDiv);

                    $('#category_id' + i).filterMultiSelect({
                        placeholderText: "Please select",
                    });
                }
                buttonsDiv.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example if the Part 1 selected "Food&Drink" and "Housing" options, then at Part 2 those circled option should be disabled or remove, only if the Part 1 uncheck it the Part 2 will able to select them again.
[image: example]

Comment: Is this Laravel related at all? If not, please click [edit], then `[<>]` and create a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML and relevant script (and plugins/frameworks) and css

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you show perhaps a picture of before and after. Aslo the code is not clear since the laravel {{}} does not show the categories. I have written a version that is much simple but need to see a [mcve] from you

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a Laravel problem?